# Finding a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a little problem by finding a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

My problem is that we have $+$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\cdot$ in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Given *any* element $g\in \mathbb{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$, you get a homomorphism: $\phi(n)=g^n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define $\phi: \mathbb Z \to GL_2(\mathbb Z)$, by $$
\phi(n) = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right), \,\,\, n \in \mathbb Z.
$$ Notice $$\phi(n) \phi(m) =\left(\begin{matrix}1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1 & m \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & n+m \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) = \phi(n+m), \,\,\,\, n,m \in \mathbb Z.$$

Comment: Thats it! Is in particular a homomorphism to $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. It is possible to define two different homomorphisms $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with $f(n,0)=\begin{pmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $f(0,n)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\n&1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @user114179 I don't think so. The two matrices don't commute in $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: It unclear to me what you're asking. You seem to be referring to one map $f:\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z\to M_2(\mathbb Z)$ defined (something like) $$f(n,m) = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & n \\ m & 1 \end{matrix} \right), \,\,\, (n,m) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z.$$ This isn't a homomorphism for a number of reasons. First of all, it doesn't actually map into $GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ since $m = n = 1$ gives a non-invertible matrix.

Comment: Here is what I want: We have two maps $e_1:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},~n\mapsto (n,0)$ and $e_2$ similar with $e_2(n)=(0,n)$. Now I want to find two grouphomomorphisms $f_1,f_2:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such there is either no group homomorphism or more than one $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $f\circ e_i = f_i$ for $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 1):

Try
$$
n \mapsto \pmatrix{1 & n \\ 0 & 1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The target group is the group of non-linear  transformations of plane that preserves a lattice. Given an integer $n$ look at the transformation that moves the lattice points $n$ steps to the right if $n>0$, or $|n|$ steps to the left if $n<0$.

As doing the transformations corresponding to $n$ steps followed by $m$ steps has the same net result as doing a single linear transformation of $n+m$ steps, this is indeed a group homomorphism that you desired.

My answer is geometric formulation of the algebraic version given by lhf and User81828.